# Captured image from a Windows Installation Media using PowerISO contains "System Volume Information"

Tags: filesystems, iso-image, livecd, liveusb

So, I have a modified Windows 11 Installation media flashed into my USB drive (actually just the vanilla Windows 11 ISO that I selected for no TPM/no SecureBoot/no RAM requirements using Rufus).

I then captured it via PowerISO's "Make USB drive image" to create an *.img image. In the volume, a folder named "System Volume Information" appears that did not exist in the USB drive or vanilla ISO. I simply ignored this fact as something harmless. I went on to unpack the img  to then be compiled together to make a bootable ISO. When I burnt the resulting ISO to a Blu-ray, the BD can boot. Yet, when I flash it to a USB drive, flashing cannot complete: \System Volume Information\IndexerVolumeGuid & \System Volume Information\WPSettings.dat are access denied.

Is \System Volume Information a critical folder? Should I simply delete it in the ISO or is it something that needs attending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among other things, Windows stores System Restore points in the
System Volume Information folder.

On NTFS, Windows won’t normally let you access this folder, much less
delete it. But since your ISO is not a working disk and not even NTFS,
you may safely remove it.

Reference :
[What Is the “System Volume Information” Folder, and Can I Delete It?](https://www.howtogeek.com/282214/what-is-the-system-volume-information-folder-and-can-i-delete-it/)

Comment: @TempusNomen - It wasn’t created by Rufus

Comment: Does PowerISO leave the option of copying the partition table & filesystems to single storage device?

Answer (score 0):

> I then captured it via PowerISO's "Make USB drive image" to create an *.img image

Not an answer to your question, but I'm just going to indicate that you could just create your `*.img` using Rufus itself.

You just have to click *Show advanced properties* in Rufus and once you have done that, you will see that a blue "Save" icon appears next to the currently selected drive. Click that icon, and Rufus will allow you to create an **uncompressed** `.vhd` image, which, for all intents and purposes can be used in the exact same way as a `.img` (since it's basically a `dd` dump with an extra 512-byte footer added, and that footer will not interfere in the slightest if you choose to use the image as a `dd` image).

So, there was no need to use Rufus + PowerISO. Just Rufus was enough.

As to `System Volume Information` this is indeed created automatically by Windows and it won't interfere with the bootability of your media.

Comment: The very creator of Rufus joining in the discussion... Thanks for the input. I'll try it out the future.